# How to fill redis with redis-cli with dummy data of size weigh hundreds of MB?

Tags: performance, redis, monitoring, health-monitoring

I am getting my hand dirty with redis monitoring. So far I came up with this metrics useful to monitor about redis:

- memory_used
- through put
- latency
- connections
- replication

I am newbie on this. I am trying to fill the redis from redis-cli with dummy data as:

 `` for i in `seq 10000000`; do redis-cli SET users:app "{id: '$i', name: 'name$i', address: 'address$i' }" ; done ``

but it doesn't scale my need to fillup the redis-db fast enough...

Also I need some help regarding the latency and throught put monitoring. I know what they mean, but I don't know how to measure them... My eyes don't see anything rellated to that on output for `redis-cli info`

Thanks, for support/guidence :D

Comment: Latency and throughput depend on the commands that you're running and where you're running them from - are you trying to synthetically load stress it or check a real app? For load stressing use `redis-benchmark` (part of the Redis project) or `memtier_benchmark` (source: https://github.com/redislabs/memtier_benchmark)

Answer (score 13):

Use the undocumented `DEBUG POPULATE` command.

`DEBUG POPULATE count [prefix] [size]`: Create `count` string keys named `key:<num>`. If a prefix is specified it's used instead of the `key` prefix.

The value starts with `value:<num>` and is filled with null chars if needed until it achieves the given `size` if specified.

```
> DEBUG POPULATE 5 test 1000000
OK
> KEYS *
1) "test:3"
2) "test:1"
3) "test:4"
4) "test:2"
5) "test:0"
> STRLEN test:0
(integer) 1000000
> STRLEN test:4
(integer) 1000000
> GETRANGE test:1 0 10
"value:1\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

Comment: Seems this command does not support redis cluster

Comment: What's the problem you are seeing?

Comment: This command works but does not respect the `maxmemory` setting so it requires to be careful.

Answer (score 1):

To "fill fast", follow the instructions in the documentation about [Mass Insert](http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert) - the gist is using the `--pipe` directive on a pre-prepared data file.

Answer (score 1):

following @leomurillo

I got this to work without the last parameter, and I couldn't find the documentation for this undocumented command :)

`127.0.0.1:6379> DEBUG POPULATE 10000000 PHPREDIS_SESSION
OK
(15.61s)
127.0.0.1:6379> dbsize
(integer) 10000334`

Answer (score 1):

Using Python

`redis-dummy-data-generator.py`, Creates 10000 key-value pairs

```
#!/usr/bin/python
for i in range(10000):
  print 'set name'+str(i),'helloworld'
```

Run generator script and store the output in `redis_commands.txt` file

`python redis-dummy-data-generator.py > redis_commands.txt`

Load generated dummy data into redis-server

`redis-cli -a mypassword -h localhost -p 6379  < redis_commands.txt`